# VHDL code for turning 50MHz into 38KHz doesn't work

Tags: vhdl

I'm having an issue with this code. Theoretically it should turn my 50MHz sign into 36KHz but as i run the simulation it turns out that the ir_38khz doesn't get any value it is unassigned.

Can you help me where i slip?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity orajelKonverter is
    Port ( clk50 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           ir_38khz : out  STD_LOGIC);
end orajelKonverter;

architecture Behavioral of orajelKonverter is

signal hz38_ctr : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
signal s38 : std_logic;

begin

clk_generator : process (clk50, rst)

begin
    if rst = '1' then
        s38 <= '0';
        hz38_ctr <= (others => '0');

    elsif clk50='1' then

        if hz38_ctr = "1010010010" then
            hz38_ctr <= (others => '0');
            s38 <= not s38;
        else
            hz38_ctr <= hz38_ctr + "1";
        end if;
    end if;
end process clk_generator;

ir_38khz <= s38;

end Behavioral;
```

Here is the picture from the simulation:
[image: the problem itself]

Comment: use `rising_edge(clk50)` rather than detecting its level is '1'... I would also use a ranged integer for your counter...

Comment: Brian i tried out to use rising_edge(clk50) but the result is just the same as before.

Comment: If you open the DUT in the "Instances and processes" window, you can add all its signals to the sim (and restart/rerun it). Seeing what's going on inside it will probably show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your signals to some value OR assert your reset to initialize them in simulation.  I personally prefer #1, since signal initial conditions *are* synthesizable, despite the relatively common misconception that they are not.  As a matter of fact, I avoid resets in my designs unless I absolutely need to use them.  This is actually [recommended by Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp272.pdf).  So for example you can do:

```
signal s38 : std_logic := '0';
```

This will guarantee that when your simulation starts it knows what to do with the line:

```
s38 <= not s38;
```

Previously the simulator was trying to do `not U` which is `U`.

Comment: No (to initial values), but yes to reset ... the Reset clause will do that correctly ... as long as he actually drives Reset to '1' and back to '0' in the testbench.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I disagree about using reset.  Read that Xilinx whitepaper that I added in my answer.  I approach my designs with that philosophy.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that paper. Resets still have their place, you don't always want to reconfigure just to reset. But Ken certainly makes good points and rovers the problems of resetting large designs nicely.